# fade out image on one div but triggers image to fade in on other div with same class

Tags: jquery

I have an image panel, that when clicked, it fades out and shows a video behind it. When I click on another one id like it to do the same action, but the previous item, which had already had the image fade out and video showing, to fade the image back in and cover that video.

Meaning that this is only one video showing at a time.

jQuery:

```
$( ".video-link" ).click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="item" data-factor="1">
                        <div class="video-panel-wrap">
                            <div class="video-link">
                                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('video_image'); ?>" />
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <h3><?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?></h3>
                                            <span class="excerpt"><?php the_sub_field('video_description'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-player">

                                    <?php if( get_sub_field('vimeo') ): ?>
                                         <iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                     <?php endif; ?>
                                     <?php if( get_sub_field('youtube') ): ?>
                                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                     <?php endif; ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$( ".video-link" ).click(function() {

    // Fade back in all but the clicked video-link
    $(".video-link").not(this).fadeIn();

    // Just fadeout the clicked one
    $(this).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```

If this causes a `fadeIn` of existing elements, you can either check if they are visible or not, or simply animate the opacity to 0 instead (will not change those that are already at opacity 0).

```
$( ".video-link" ).click(function() {

    // Fade back in all but the clicked video-link
    $(".video-link").not(this).animate({opacity: 0});

    // Just fadeout the clicked one
    $(this).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```